# Gmail / gsuite addon - Automatically open on mailbox open

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace

When a user logs in to their gmail mailbox from a browser, the addon is visable on the right hand side, but requires the user to proactively click it to open. It builds the card and works as expected.

However, I do not want this addon to require proactive users to click it to open it.

Ideal option 1) On opening mailbox or reading a received mail, the addon opens and continues to build the card as in the manifest.

option 2) The icon grabs the attention of the user or requests in some manner to be opened.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to automatically open the Add-on, unless you simulate the click using an [extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide). However, a simpler solution to catch the user's attention could be using a gif for the `logoUrl` parameter in the [manifest file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#common)  of the Add-on.